# How can I change the currency on the Y-axis?

Tags: pine-script

I would like the value of Crude Oil on the vertical axis of its graph - which is expressed in USD - to be expressed in EUR (at the current EURUSD rate, of course). How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really a Pine question, but use a [spread](https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/spread-charts-now-on-tradingview-98/): `CL1!/EURUSD`.